# How can I re-run a unit test X-amount of times?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, resharper

My problem is that my unit tests fails from time to time. Most of the times it is successful.
I would like to run it X amount of times or just repeat the test case until it fails.

What I can do is to just click on the test and rerun it once more even though it has been successful run, but that is time consuming.

I have had a look in Visual Studio in "Test Explorer" and Resharper "Unit Test Session", but I can find a smart way to rerun all test until it fails.

Is there another way?

Best Regards,
Hans

Comment: You need to fix the bug that is causing it to fail first as unit tests should run consistently every time. It is not a very good test if you need to run it multiple times to make sure it works.

Comment: You are right, but it rarely happens and it happens in daily test. So when I try to debug the test case locally it does not fail. That is why I thought that I can perhaps run it multiple times until one of the test cases fails in debug then see what is happening.

Comment: Is it your unit test code that fails or the code that the test is testing? Your unit test should be as small as possible and only testing one thing. You could put a for loop around your testing code to see if that helps. Maybe you could post your unit test code. intermittent failures are a pain to track down.

Comment: @PiersMyers If the bug that causes it to fail is stochastic, then yes, it may fail at random. This is the case for me, as the code I'm testing is simulating physics.

Answer (score 18):

I see you mention you have ReSharper - in the Resharper unit test session window you can select the test you are interested in, then click the drop-down next to the Run button and there is a "Run Unit Tests Until Fail" option

Also, see [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Executing_Analyzing_Tests.html#executing)